# Перенос строки поиска regex

Tags: python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите как перенести шаблон поиска на новую строку, чтобы он не был такой длинный?

```
r'.[quote]+\b.{2}\s.{2}[id]+\b.{2}\s([0-9]+).\s.[code]+\b.{2}\s.([-.0-9A-Z]+).{2}\s.[fullUrl]+\b.{2}\s.([-/0-9a-z]+).{2}\s.[title]+\b.{2}\s.([-.()0-9A-Z]+)'
```

Comment: Разделите просто на две строки через `+`.

Comment: Только этот шаблон всё равно не будет работать правильно. `[code]+` найдет `odeco`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При вызове большинства функций из модуля `re`, можно указать флаг `re.X`. Он позволяет использовать пробелы и комментарии в регулярном выражении.

```
import re

r = re.compile(r'''
    \w+ # первое слово
    \   # пробел (экранируется)
    \w+ # второе слово
''', re.X)

print(r.match('Слава роботам'))
```